# How can I fix this finger rig?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm really stuck and confused as to what's wrong with my hand/finger rig. In my reference model I'm trying to copy, the green controller bone for the little finger moves the finger and is connected to the red hand deform bone. I can't seem to get it to work though. In an earlier save, my green control bone is connected to the green hand deform bone and it works. Either one I try, it doesn't work now.

Also, if I set up the IK constraint like the reference model, and put the pole angle at 90 degrees and have the influence at 1, the finger twists upwards, whereas in the model I'm copying, it isn't like that.

[image]

Comment: Anyone? :( Otherwise I may have to try deleting every hand and finger bone and start again, which I don't fancy doing. And even then the problem may still persist.

Comment: I can't open your file (tried 2.79 and 2.8)

Comment: Odd. Downloaded and tried it and it opens fine for me. I'll try re-uploading it.

Comment: As an aside: I've noticed there's a strange green line pointing to the origin in the centre and I'm not sure how to get rid of it.

Comment: Is the save working for anyone?